# Can not compile Main.java

Tags: compiler-errors

This is my first post here, and also I'm a beginer in learning java.

I'm watching an online course, and it seems that I can not receive the output of $javac Main.java because I receive this error message in powershell 7.3.5, in IntelliJ IDEA:

```
ParserError: 
Line |
   1 |  $javac main.java
     |         ~~~~~~~~~
     | Unexpected token 'main.java' in expression or statement.
```

Can anyone please help me?

Also, here is a picture:

[line-of-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/004Im.png)

Thank you!

I tried to look ths up, but I did not find anything...

Comment: Please post code as text, not an image of text.